# Fixed points of iterated permutations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider an arbitrary composition $g_n=f\circ\cdots\circ f\ (n\text{ times})$ of a bijective function 
$$f \colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$$ (a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$). I need to show that for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x=g_n(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$  by
\begin{equation}
f (n) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } n = 0 \\
n - 2 &\text{if } n > 0 \text{ is even} \\
n + 2 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then $f$ is a bijection and $\forall n, x \in \mathbb{N}, f^n (x) \neq x$.

More generally, for a countably infinite set $A$, choose $\phi \colon \mathbb{N} \to A$ an enumeration of $A$; then $\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is a bijection $\psi \colon A \to A$ such that $\forall x \in A, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \psi^n (x) \neq x$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is not possible without further assumptions. Suppose $A=\mathbb{Z}$, and consider $f:A\rightarrow A$ defined by $f(x)=x+1.$ Then $f$ is clearly a bijection, but $g_{n}(x)=x+n\neq x$ for any $n\geq 1.$

Comment: One such assumption which would allow getting the conclusion is if you assume $A$ is finite.  Then $g_m(x) = g_n(x)$ for some $m > n$ (by a pigeonhole principle type argument), and then the injectivity of $f$ implies $g_{m-n}(x) = x$.

Comment: Is it posible for $A=\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: This answer was posted when the question had $f:A\rightarrow A$ as a bijection, with $A$ arbitrary.